# inflate child view above parent view in expandablelistview

Tags: android, listview, expandable

[see the image first here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOMIX.png)

The orange label contains some value and it is the parent list and the three images you are seeing is the child list coming through an array, I don't understand how to place the parent view below the child view in expandable list View, as the child list is not fixed but it is not null.

Comment: just for understanding - that are not parent and child views. That are *group* and *child*. I don't think that it is easily possible to achieve this with the ExpandableListVIew. It should be easier to do with RecyclerView and custom layout manager

Comment: You can manage it through single list item layout too